# Using a DataTable as a Returning Value

Tags: c#, datatable

I am trying to find all the txt files in a directory.

thisdir returns a datatable of two columns of data and is correct.

I am having trouble with dirsort recognizing thisdir

```
    protected void display(string dir)
    {
        DataTable dirsort = new DataTable(thisdir(dir));
        DataTable dirout = new DataTable();
        dirout.Columns.Add("Name");
        dirout.Columns.Add("Size");
        foreach (string txtFile in dirsort)
        {
            if(txtFile["File"].Substring(Len(txtFile["File"])-3,3)) == "txt")
            {
                dirout.Rows.Add(txtFile["File"], Folder["Size"]);
            }
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = dirout;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    protected static DataTable thisdir(string dir)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("File");
        dt.Columns.Add("Size");
        ...
        string file = ftpReader.ReadLine().ToString();
        string size = ftpfilesize(dir, file);
        dt.Rows.Add(file, size);
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: why `DataTable dirsort = new DataTable(thisdir(dir));` instead of `DataTable dirsort = thisdir(dir);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
DataTable dirsort = thisdir(dir);
```